# is it possible to get the analog value of proximity sensor flutter apps

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to use the proximity sensor and wondering if there is a way to get the analog value. Currently with the following two plugins, it seems like it only can get a "yes", "no" or "true", "false" value.

Is there anyway to actually get the analog value so i can calculate the distance?

https://pub.dev/packages/all_sensors
https://github.com/Samaritan1011001/proximity_plugin

Answer (score 0):

getting distance is not possible in ios. you can get just true or false. but in android , it is possible. it depends on which platform you should support. maybe this will help.  https://pub.dev/packages/proximity_sensor